# Final Project on CS50ide, AJAX url not found

Tags: ajax, cs50

I want to use AJAX in my final project, so first I wanted to test Doug's code from the AJAX shorts tutorial. I literally copied his code, put my all my "html" files into templates folder, but when I try running it, it says that the url is not found.

Here is a screenshot, I really have no idea what the issue could be.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZtvD.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are using Flask which sits in front of any html. When you're going to index.html for instance you are going to / and then Flask is rendering index.html.

So what you are doing there is telling the browser to access name + ".html" but the browser can't access any HTML files.

Comment: Thank you, do you know if there is any way I can make it work?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never used AJAX, but there must be a Flask + Ajax tutorial somewhere?